# How to update links with common header file using javascript or nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

I would like to know how to update links for all pages.

I have common header file which holds navbar having dropdown with languages.
currently, am using same header file for all pages,
Lets say if i select a dropdown languages it navigates to backend route,

when dropdown is selection made
On Index page, dropdown url should be ``` /en``/th ```,
On About page, dropdown url should be `/en/about` `/th/about`
On Contact page, dropdown url should be `/en/contact`, `th/about`

so my question is since I have a common header, when I go the respective pages , how do i update links in dropdown url.
How to do using frontend/backend, bit confused

```
//language.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'});
});
module.exports = router;
//aboutus.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('aboutus.ejs');
});
module.exports = router;


header.ejs

<body>
  <nav>
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/en/about" style="margin-right: 1.5rem!important;">about us</a>
          </li>
          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/en/contact"
              style="margin-right: 1.5rem!important;">contact us</a>
          </li>
  </ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="language" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="clickButton()">
        English
      </button>
      <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" onclick="clickItem(); return false">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/en">English</a> //change this link according to the page
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/th">Thai</a>//change this link according to the page
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

//index.ejs

  <%- include header.ejs %>
  <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
//about.ejs

  <%- include header.ejs %>
  <h1>About us</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" onclick="clickItem(); return false">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:" onclick="updateLang("en")">English</a> //change this link according to the page
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:" onclick="updateLang("th")">Thai</a>//change this link according to the page
  </div>
```

```
Script for the updatelang
updateLang(val){
 var url = new URL(location.href);
 var query_string = url.search;
 var search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string); 

 // new value of "lang" is set to "th" val = "th"
 search_params.set('lang', val);

 // change the search property of the main url
 url.search = search_params.toString();

 // the new url string
 var new_url = url.toString();

 // output : http://demourl.com/path?lang=th
 console.log(new_url);
 location.replace(new_url)
}


you can send query parameter to backend
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   let lang = req.query.lang;
// based on lang you can send file
   res.render('aboutus.ejs');
});
```

Comment: thanks for help, is it possible to do using ajax call request

Comment: have updated mycode, when i click  on `about us` and dropdown is `thai`, will replace the url as `/th/about` as route?

Comment: is it possible to replace set params as `http://demourl.com/path/:lang`

Comment: location.pathname.split('/')[2]; you will get lang value, Happy coding.